# How to use key pair generated by openpgp in go

Tags: go, rsa, openpgp

I'm trying to generate keypair with openpgp lib and when I want to test it by encrypting a test string, it returns the following error `openpgp: invalid argument: cannot encrypt because no candidate hash functions are compiled in. (Wanted RIPEMD160 in this case.)`. However it works when I pass a public key exported from gpg.

Also I'm wondering how to encrypt the private key like `gpg --generate-key` does?

```
func main() {
    var e *openpgp.Entity
    var pubKey *bytes.Buffer

    e, _ = openpgp.NewEntity("testUser", "test", "test@test.test", nil)

    for _, id := range e.Identities {
        err := id.SelfSignature.SignUserId(id.UserId.Id, e.PrimaryKey, e.PrivateKey, nil)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
    }

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    w, err := armor.Encode(buf, openpgp.PublicKeyType, nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    e.Serialize(w)
    w.Close()
    pubKey = buf

    // Encrypting test with public key 
    entity, err := openpgp.ReadArmoredKeyRing(pubKey)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    buf = new(bytes.Buffer)

    encoderWriter, err := armor.Encode(buf, "PGP MESSAGE", make(map[string]string))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    encryptorWriter, err := openpgp.Encrypt(encoderWriter, entity, nil, nil, nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    encryptorWriter.Write([]byte("hello world"))
    encryptorWriter.Close()
    encoderWriter.Close()

    fmt.Println(buf.String())
}
```

Comment: you have to import it using a blank import `_ "golang.org/x/crypto/ripemd160"`

Comment: Weird, the doc says that ripemd160 is deprecated. Opengpg isn't supposed to use sha256 by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same error.

#### TL; DR

- It seems that it's an abandoned bug of the `golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp` package.
- `golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp` package is frozen and deprecated. (= `wontfix`)
- Use a [patched fork package](https://github.com/ProtonMail/go-crypto) instead.

  - [`github.com/ProtonMail/go-crypto`](https://github.com/ProtonMail/go-crypto) package @ GitHub

#### TS; DR

Since the official "`golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp`" package was frozen and deprecated, as long as we use the "`golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp`" package, it seems that the only current workaround is to either;

1. Downgrade the Go version and the package, then blank import "`_ golang.org/x/crypto/ripemd160`" as @mh-cbon [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766879/how-to-use-key-pair-generated-by-openpgp-in-go#comment118024535_66766879).
2. Patch the rejected PR on your own. (Rejected due to the freezing of `x/crypto/openpgp` package)

   - Patch: https://github.com/golang/crypto/pull/128/files
   - PR: [Use correct default hashes and default ciphers when no preferences given](https://github.com/golang/crypto/pull/128)

But I had to implement an OpenPGP key pair generator on Go 1.16.6. <sub><sup>Don't ask why...</sup></sub>

So, **my current alternative was to use the forked package**. Which was [one of the abounding forks that the Go team mentioned as a sample](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44226).

- [`github.com/ProtonMail/go-crypto`](https://github.com/ProtonMail/go-crypto) package @ GitHub

  1. `go get github.com/ProtonMail/go-crypto`
  2. Remove `golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp` from `go.mod`
  3. Replace all the "`golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp`" to `"github.com/ProtonMail/go-crypto/openpgp"` in the source code.
  4. `go mod tidy`

#### References

1. "[x/crypto/openpgp: mark as frozen and deprecated](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44226)" | Issue #44226 | go | golang @ GitHub
2. "[x/crypto/openpgp: new entities cannot be encrypted to by default](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37646)" | Issue #37646 | go | golang @ GitHub
3. "[x/crypto/openpgp: new entities cannot be encrypted to by default](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12153)" | Issue #12153 | go | golang @ GitHub

Comment: After some research, I also went with the proton's fork but forgot to update my post. Thanks for you're clear and helpful response!