# Read file from folder then encrypt and decrypt it using GPG/PGP

Tags: go, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

I am trying to encrypt a file using GPG and then decrypt it whenever required.
I saw an example to encrypt it

https://gist.github.com/ayubmalik/a83ee23c7c700cdce2f8c5bf5f2e9f20

But, there is nothing described about how to decrypt it

There is one more example that allows String or text encryption and decryption

https://gist.github.com/stuart-warren/93750a142d3de4e8fdd2.

But, I have to work on files. Can anyone help me to find the solution to it?